# Node server not responding to socket.io requests over HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, sockets

No idea why this is happening. The socket.io client is trying to connect on the front end:

[image]

from `https://mywebsite.com:3000`, But no response is being received from my node.js server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var server = require('http').Server(app);

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var redis = require('ioredis');
var Redis = new redis();

Redis.subscribe('live-updates');

Redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

And the node server is running and listening successfully in the background using forever. Yet, there's no handshaking occurring. What's going on here?

Does the fact that I'm using SSL have something to do with this?

#### Edit

I have updated my node.js server configuration the the following, and am still stuck where I began.

```
var app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var io = require('socket.io')(https);

var redis = require('ioredis');
var Redis = new redis();

Redis.subscribe('live-updates');

Redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com/17710/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl/mysite.com/17710/server.crt')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening');
});
```

Comment: Is console.log(message); working?

Comment: well yes you have to configure SSL , also try `app.listen(port,callback)` instead of using `http` module

Comment: How do I "configure SSL"? Tried `app.listen` instead too, still not working.

Comment: take a look here http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen , https://nodejs.org/api/https.html

Comment: GeoPhoenix, thanks, those links are helpful, and I think I've got it nearly configured. re: the keys and certificates, what should those be? should they be a reference to my server's current cert or do I need to generate a new one for node? I'm not much of a server guy.

Comment: I've added my server keys and cert and I'm still stuck where I began. No response from node.js.